# Selenium grid: browser always has horizontal scroll

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-grid

Selenium grid: browser always has horizontal scroll.

```
http://localhost:7900   (noVNC)
```

image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

It does not happen if running tests on host.

How to make view width 100% so that horizontal scroll will not show?